# Swift simd vector bug

Tags: swift, swift2, simd

I believe there is a bug of some sort in Swift simd vectors (double2, double3, float4...)

To reproduce paste the following code in a OSX playground of Swift 2.2 Xcode 7.3.1

```
import Cocoa
import SceneKit

public protocol RealVector {
    var x: Double { get set }
    var y: Double { get set }
    var z: Double { get set }
    var w: Double { get set }
}

extension double2: RealVector {
    public var z: Double { get { return 0 } set {  } }
    public var w: Double { get { return 0 } set {  } }
}

let i = double3(x: 1, y: 2, z: 5)
```

Here is the result I am getting

[image: Result]

Please note the x value of 'i' is 5 and not 1

Can anyone confirm this?  I have tried on multiple computers.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, shows `double3(1.0, 2.0, 5.0)` correctly.

Comment: I *can* reproduce the issue, it shows `double3(5.0, 2.0, 5.0)` in my Xcode 7.3.1 Playground as well – but not in a compiled project.

Comment: Thank you I thought I was going crazy.  I have noticed it is ok in a compiled project also.  I will go ahead and write it up

Comment: Definitely a bug. If you add `let j = double2(x: 1, y: 2)` in the Playground then `i` displays correctly again.

Comment: Written up at [issue](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2042)

Comment: It also works *correctly* in my Xcode 8 beta 2 Playground.

Comment: Confirmed not an issue in Xcode 8 beta 2 Playground so hopefully it is fixed.